# Move prestashop admin folder to root directory of webstore

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

Currently, I have prestashop web store, which has shop URL and admin URL in following pattern:

*Shop URL* `http://t****s.com/index.php`

*Admin Panel URL* `http://t****s.com/demo/admin6068`

So, I want to make admin URL like `http://t****s.com/admin6068`

Is this possible?

P.S. I already try with moving all content of demo folder to outside of demo folder.

Comment: Yes is possible, move the `admin6068` folder outside `demo` folder. You have already tried, so?

Comment: @sarcom ,yes i already tried . but when i try to access it no css and js found after login in admin panel.

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache?

Comment: Your Admin Panel URL is http://t****s.com/demo/admin6068, you Shop URL should be http://t****s.com/demo

Comment: Your Admin Panel URL is http://t****s.com/demo/admin6068, you Shop URL should be http://t****s.com/demo if so in SEO and URLS > preferences  add /demo/ to BASE URI

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just move admin6068 folder to your Prestashop root folder.

Good luck.